# Schedule & automate Outlook archiving for clients in Windows Domain?

Tags: windows, group-policy, outlook, automation, outlook-2010

Schedule & automate Outlook archiving for clients in Windows domain?

I am open to mechanisms leveraging Group Policy or even other ways if it can be executed for groups of machines without using GPO.

Is it possible to define and implement scheduled Outlook cleanup & automatic archiving mechanism policies, settings for client / groups on the domain?

This came up while looking for group policies that configure/manage Outlook and Office settings for Windows machines on a domain. https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/policies.htm

Considering auto archiving on the client drive itself on a regular basis (as their incoming email is slowing Outlook down big time), that's accessible to them and maybe as a bonus once in a quarter or annually to a network/shared location.

Thoughts? If so, where and how can this be done?

Comment: Do you have Standard CALs or Enterprise CALs for Exchange client licenses? Standard or Enterprise Server license?

Comment: We have SBS (exchange is not being used anymore), but currently the org machines are using Outlook + Gmail apps via IMAP

Answer (score 1):

Once you get started with using Group Policy Objects in Active Directory, you can create a new GPO to manage Outlook settings. Be sure to download those Office ADMX files and put them in the proper folder first, as noted in the article.

In the Group Policy Management Editor, you'll need to expand the GPO navigation nodes on the left through the following path:

```
User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Microsoft Outlook 2010 > Outlook Options > Other > AutoArchive.
```

[image: GPO User Configuration Section]

The AutoArchive settings container lets you turn on AutoArchive, specify how often to let it run, and what to do with the mailbox items.

[image: Group Policy AutoArchive Settings for Outlook 2010]